# Перенос mapping' a

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть метод в коллекторе

```
fun collectEnabledAccountsGroupByLogin(selectedGuid: String): List<AccountSelectItem> {
return RealmManager.realm.where(Account::class.java).equalTo(KEY_ENABLED, true)
        .findAllSorted(arrayOf(KEY_LOGINGUID, KEY_NAME), arrayOf(Sort.ASCENDING, Sort.ASCENDING))
        .map { AccountSelectItem(it.guid, it.name, it.getCurrencyCode(), selectedGuid == it.guid) }
```

Хочу мой mapping перенести в presenter. Как можно корректно это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну примерно так пожалуй

```
fun collectAccountsInPresenter(selectedGuid: String): List<AccountSelectItem> {
    return collectEnabledAccountsGroupByLogin()
            .map { AccountSelectItem(it.guid, it.name, it.getCurrencyCode(), selectedGuid == it.guid) }
}
```